# xmobar : gaps on the right of xbm icons

Tags: xmobar

I am having a problem displaying xbm icons properly in my xmobar; namely, there is what appears to be a 1px gap on the right of some of the xbms:

[image: xmobar]

From some experimentation, it seems that the gaps only occur in the sections of the template that are between the separator char ('%') which separates plugins from straight text.

As an example, the code I am using to format the memory usage portion of the bar (first purple section from the left) is:

```
<fc=#442244,#222244><icon=right_div.xbm/>%memory%</fc>·
```

and the 'memory' plugin has a template of:

```
<fc=#555555,#442244><icon=mem.xbm/> <usedratio> </fc>
```

Note that the 'right_div.xbm' displayed fine, but the 'mem.xbm' (which is nested in '%' chars) has a gap.

All of the xbm's are the same size (width:8px, height:14px), and I have tried adjusting the width of the icons in an attempt attempt to fill the gap. This had no effect.

Has anyone encountered this before, or know of a fix to remove the gaps?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: May I ask, where are you getting these icons from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what the issue was, but it was fixed when I switched to using cabal's version by running the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove xmobar

cabal install xmobar --flags="with_xft"
```

Hope this helps anyone else that is having this issue!